# How Can I Fix my Method to Update the Derivative Sum of Squares -- Linear Model?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, math, gradient-descent

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days right now, but with no success. I showered over stack overflow but have not yet found the answer to my problem. In essence, we have our derivative sum of squares function (drss) which should update the betas, but it is not currently achieving that goal. calcError and y_pred are helper functions for drss. For the parameters betas = np.array(0.0, 0.0) (betas[0] is the intercept), x is the input column of a pandas dataframe, and y is the output column of a pandas dataframe. I feel this code is very close, but I would appreciate help just tweeking this. Thanks in advance for your help. You are really helping not just one but two struggling students.

```
def calcError(betas, x, y):
    return np.sum((betas[0] + betas[1]*x - y)**2)

def y_pred(betas, x):
    return betas[0] + betas[1]*x

def dRSS(betas, x, y, learning_rate):
    n = float(len(x))
    new_betas = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    db0 = betas[0] - learning_rate*(2.0/n)*np.sum(y_pred(betas,x)-y)
    db1 = betas[1] - learning_rate*(2.0/n)*np.sum(x*(y_pred(betas,x)-y))
    
    new_betas[0] = db0
    new_betas[1] = db1
    return new_betas
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating `sum((betas[0] + betas[1]*x - y)**2)` you will calculate the sum of several terms of the form `(beta[0] + beta[1]*x - y)**2`

You must be aware that the derivative of `(f)**2` is `2 * df * f`

the derivative of `(beta[0] + beta[1] - y` w.r.t `beta[0]` is 1, and w.r.t `beta[1]` is `x`.

so your derivatives of with respect to beta[0] and beta[1] can be calculated as follow

```py
def calcGrad(betas, x, y):
    f = (betas[0] + betas[1] * x - y)
    dbeta0 = 2 * np.sum(1 * f);
    dbeta1 = 2 * np.sum(x * f);
    return [dbeta0, dbeta1]
```

Then if you want to update beta using gradient descent you simply do

```py
dbeta = calcGrad(betas, x, y)
beta[0] -= learning_rate * dbeta[0];
beta[0] -= learning_rate * dbeta[1];
```